# ¿Por qué si introduzco un valor var background dark en css no cambia el fondo?

Tags: css

Al momento de escribir este código en el body no me cambia a background-color var y i página no se pone en modo oscuro

```
root{
--dark : #lalala;
 --white: white ;
 --ligh-grey:  grey;
--gold: gold;
}

body{ 
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; 
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: .05rem;
background-color var(--dark);
```

Comment: Te has olvidado los : después del background-color

Comment: También de los dos puntos delante de `root`

Answer (score 3):

el problema es el ( `--dark : #lalala;` ), debería ser #1a1a1a (estas usando L en vez de 1 y no arroja ningun color ese valor, exceptuando por 1a1a1a que es un gris muy oscuro ),igual te faltaron los dos puntos antes del root (`:root`) y despues del background-color  (`background-color: var(--dark);`), el codigo te quedaria asi

```css
:root{
    --dark : #1a1a1a;
    --white: white ;
    --ligh-grey:  grey;
    --gold: gold;
    }
    
    body{ 
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; 
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: .05rem;
      background-color: var(--dark); 
    }
```

Comment: Puede que tengas razón. Pero esa no es la solución definitiva o completa. Lo digo porque a cambiar solo eso no me genera ningun resultado. Por favor mejora tu respuesta. Te invito a leer: [¿Como hacer una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)